# Set mouse pointer to busy during sync ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have a lot of ajax calls in my site and according to the size of data it can let the user wait 2-4 seconds. So I would like to change the mouse style to "busy" when the data are loaded from server. I have already found, that the async ajax calls are can be well done by using the global code like this:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function (){
    $('body').addClass('wait');
}).ajaxComplete(function () {
    $('body').removeClass('wait');
});
```

It works pretty well. The problem is, what should I do to those sync functions? 
 I need at somewhere the async: false. So if there are not other ways to get around it. I would rather manuelly write in every sync ajax calls the same code than rewrite every ajax calls to async. Cause it is not so easy like change the false to true. The only way I find is to manuelly add the codes before the ajax call and also after the ajax call (I mean in success) like this:

```js
$('html, body').css("cursor", "wait");
$.ajax({
  url: //your url
  type: //your type post or get 
  dataType: "html",
  data: //data send by ajax
  success: function(returnData) {
    $('html, body').css("cursor", "default");
    //any other actions ....
  },
  error: function(e) {
    alert(e);
  }
});
```

It will work, but I have more than 20 js files and I don't even know how many ajax calls I have. So I would like to ask if there are another way to get around with it so I don't need to write like 50+ times the same codes in every ajax call?

Comment: Your first example, using global  `ajaxSend()` and `ajaxComplete()` handlers, is the solution you need. Why does it not work for you?

Comment: just remove `$('html, body').css("cursor", "default");` from your `success` callback and (of course) have the `wait` class behave correctly in your css.

Comment: by the ajax calls which are set to async: false, it will freeze the browser during the loading of data and the mouse pointer won't change (also freezed).

Comment: No, you need to add the code in every ajax if you need it in everyone

Comment: @ashik no you don't, that's what `ajaxSend` and `ajaxComplete` are for. Unless you mean in the `async: false` case.

Comment: @MinXIE of course it freezes! You told it to be synchronous, so it blocks

Comment: @MinXIE this is exactly why you should never, ever, use `async: false`. There is nothing you can do to show content during a sync request as the browser UI is frozen. Use async requests only, with the callback pattern instead.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca the first example works only for the ajax calls which are set to asycn: true. When the ajax calls must be async: false. The whole page will freezed during the loading of data, so the mouse pointer also won't change. You need to change the mouse pointer before the sync ajax call even happens. That's why I find out the second example.

Comment: Why do you need a 'async: false'?

Comment: Also note that the AJAX in your question is async. It would have been helpful to know that from the start. I know you placed 'sync' in your title, but that appeared to be a typo given you didn't mention it again until your comment above.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The point is, I need at somewhere the async: false. So if there are not other ways to get around it. I would rather manuelly write in every sync ajax calls the same code than rewrite every ajax calls to async. Cause it is not so easy like change the false to true

Comment: `The point is, I need at somewhere the async: false` No, you don't. There is no valid reason for synchronous requests any more, except a badly designed system or poor code. If you are struggling to change your logic to async I'd suggest asking a new question about it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `No, you don't.`  Totally agree here.  But I think the OP is worried about changing 20+ places were he uses it at the moment.  Maybe a solution is to intercept `$.ajax`, and create a wrapper function.  Not clean, but as a temporally solution until he gets chance to tidy up those 20 ajax calls and convert to `async`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes I know today people always say there is no need for sync. But would you rather rewrite 20 js files to solve a mouse problem? I think the system is not so well designed but my point is really not at sync or async. Just ask if there is a way to global solve the mouse problem by sync ajax call, not "async better or sync better". Thank you by the way for the help.

Comment: Possible, although I'd say that time spent addressing the problem is better spent than hacking a solution which could cause a lot of maintenance problems in the future.

Comment: I agree with @RoryMcCrossan , the other problem you will hit using `sync` is that in modern browsers `sync` is depreciated for none web-workers, so it might work for now, but at some point your going to have to update anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could listen for the `ajaxSend` and `ajaxComplete` events and toggle a CSS class on your body which enables/disables the loading pointer as needed

```js
var $body = $('body');
$(document).ajaxSend(function(){
    $body.addClass('loading');
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    $body.removeClass('loading');
});
```

```css
body.loading{
    cursor: progress; // Or any other type you want
}
```

You may need to register a counter if you plan on tracking multiple AJAX requests in parallel. You can increment the counter each time an ajax call happens, decrement it when a call completes and remove the loading class if the counter has reached zero

Comment: I think that you did not read the question. You solution is exactly equals the presented like not useful into the question.

Comment: @PedroRamon I may have misunderstood but OP does not do what I have suggested in my answer. OP adds a class on those events but nowhere is the CSS specified to make it actually change the cursor. OP also has some code which needs to be added each time an AJAX call is made.. That is not so in this case. Can you clarify what exactly you mean?

Comment: @ChiragRavindra Sorry, I apologize for the bad description of my question, cause I am not a native speaker. Your solution works pretty good by the async ajax calls. Which I alredy tested. The question is now I need a solution to those sync ajax calls. But thank you for the answer anyway.

Comment: @MinXIE I see I understand now. I didn't see anywhere in the docs that setting `async:false` would affect the behaviour of the callback. From the docs: `These methods register handlers to be called when certain events, such as initialization or completion, take place for any Ajax request on the page. The global events are fired on each Ajax request if the global property in jQuery.ajaxSetup() is true, which it is by default. Note: Global events are never fired for cross-domain script or JSONP requests, regardless of the value of global.` Will experiment further and revert

Answer (score 1):

You can use  **`$.ajaxStart()`** and **`$.ajaxComplete()`** to set global AJAX properties that will apply for the entire page:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $('html, body').css("cursor", "wait");
});
$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    $('html, body').css("cursor", "default");
});
```

Or you can use **`$.ajaxSetup()`** method :

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('html, body').css("cursor", "wait");
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('html, body').css("cursor", "default");
    }
});
```